# Why does matchlist() return empty strings at the end of the result?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, matchlist

From the Vim's help:

```
echo matchlist('acd', '\v(a)?(b)?(c)?(.*)')
Results in: ['acd', 'a', '', 'c', 'd', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I understand why the 3rd element is an empty string: 'b' is not present in the string, but what's up with those 5 empty strings at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what's up with those 5 empty strings at the end?

`matchlist()` **always** returns the list of 10 items (the matched string and nine submatches - just like `\0, \1, ..., \9` in [`:h sub-replace-special`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special)). The last five weren't used, so they are set to empty strings.

Comment: You might want to expand this answer to explain *why* there are only submatches and the relation with the 9 backreferences `\1` through `\9`.

Comment: I wish the documentation of the function were clearer on that. Even after following all the tags it is still not clearly stated about the limit of subgroups, one just have to deduce it.

Answer (score 3):

As it has been explained, this function will always assume 9 submatches can exist and it will return an entry in the result list for all possible submatch. Hence the 5 extra elements returned.

On a practical note, this means that we cannot call it this way

```
let [all, a, b, c, end] = matchlist('acd', '\v(a)?(b)?(c)?(.*)') " fails
```

But we don't have to fill 5 dummy variables either

```
let [all, a, b, c, end, dummy5, dummy6, dummy7, dummy8, dummy9] = matchlist('acd', '\v(a)?(b)?(c)?(.*)')
```

Instead, we can use `;`. See *List unpack* chapter just  before [`:h list-modification`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#list%2dmodification) chapter in Vim documentation -- unfortunately, there is no `:h list-unpack` entry at this time.

This means the following, with the semicolon, works fine

```
let [all, a, b, c, end; dummy_tail] = matchlist('acd', '\v(a)?(b)?(c)?(.*)')
```